# Matrix exponentiation with scipy: expm, expm2 and expm3

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Matrix exponentiation can be performed in python using functions within the `scipy.linalg` library, namely `expm, expm2, expm3`. `expm` makes use of a Pade approximation; `expm2` uses the eigenvalue decomposition approach and `expm3` makes use of a Taylor series with a default number of terms of 20.

In SciPy 0.13.0 release notes it is stated that:

> The matrix exponential functions scipy.linalg.expm2 and scipy.linalg.expm3 are deprecated. All users should use the numerically more robust scipy.linalg.expm function instead.

Although `expm2` and `expm3` are deprecated since release version SciPy 0.13.0, I have found that in many situations these implementations are faster than `expm`.
From this, some questions arise:

In what situations could expm2 and expm3 result in numerical instabilities?

In what situations (e.g. sparse matrices, symmetric, ...) is each of the algorithms faster/more precise?

Comment: This question is interesting, if you don't get answers here you may also consider posting it to [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) (in terms of the algorithms you mention, not the SciPy functions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will depend a lot on the detail of the implementation of these different ways of exponentiating the matrix.

In general terms, I would expect the eigen-decomposition (`expm2`) to be poorly suited to sparse matrices, because it is likely to remove the sparseness. It will also be more difficult to apply to non-symmetric matrices, because this will require the use of complex arithmetic and more expensive algorithms to compute the eigen-decomposition.

For the Taylor-series approach (`expm3`), this sounds risky if there are a fixed number of terms independent of the norm of the matrix. When computing e^x for a scalar x, the largest terms in the Taylor series are around that for which n is close to x.

However, the implementation details of these (deprecated) functions may use tricks like diagonally loading the matrix so as to improve the stability of these series expansion.