# Difference between scipy.linalg.expm versus hand-coded one

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I was trying to implement the matrix exponential function as in `scipy.linalg.expm`. I gained inspiration from [kaityo256's github repository](https://github.com/kaityo256/lie-trotter-sample/blob/master/lie-trotter.py). I thus wrote down the following.

```
from scipy.linalg import expm
from scipy.linalg import eigh
from scipy.linalg import inv
from math import exp as math_exp
from numpy import array, zeros
from numpy.random import random_sample
from numpy.testing import assert_allclose

def diag2sqr(x):
    '''Makes an square matrix from a diagonal one.

    Takes a 1d matrix. Determines its data type.
    Finds out the shape of the 1d matrix.
    Makes an empty  square matrix with  both
    dimensions equal to largest (nonzero) dimension of
    the 1d matrix. It then fills the elements of the
    1d matrix into diagonal slots of the empty
    square one.


    Parameters
    ----------
    x : ndarray
        ndarray of be coverted to a square ndarray

    Returns
    -------
    xsqr : ndarray
        ndarray with diagonals sameas those of x
        all other elements are zero
        dtype same as that of x

    '''

    x_flat = x.ravel()
    xsqr = zeros((x_flat.shape[0], x_flat.shape[0]), dtype=x.dtype)
    # Making the empty matrix
    for i in range(x_flat.shape[0]):
        xsqr[i, i] = x_flat[i]
        # filling up the ith element

    print('xsqr', xsqr)
    return xsqr


def kaityo_expm(x, ):
    '''Exponentiates an ndarray (kaityo).

    Exponentiates a ndarray in the most naive way.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : ndarray
        The ndarray to be exponentiated

    Returns
    -------
    kexpm : ndarray
        x after exponentiating

    '''

    rx, ux = eigh(x)
    # Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    # eigenvectors composed to form a unitary
    ux_inv = inv(ux)
    # Inverse of the unitary
    # tx = diag([array([math_exp(i) for i in rx]).ravel()])
    # tx = array([math_exp(i) for i in rx])
    tx = diag2sqr(array([math_exp(i) for i in rx]))
    # Constructing the diagonal matrix
    kexpm1 = tx@ux_inv
    kexpm = ux@kexpm1

    return kexpm
```

Afterwards, I tried to test the above code versus `scipy.linalg.expm`.

```
x = random_sample((10, 10))
assert_allclose(expm(x), kaityo_expm(x))
```

This leads to the following output.

```
AssertionError: 
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0

Mismatch: 100%
Max absolute difference: 7.04655733
Max relative difference: 0.59875635
 x: array([[18.032424, 16.224408, 12.432163, 16.614248, 12.85653 , 13.705387,
        15.096966, 10.577946, 18.399573, 17.938062],
       [16.352809, 17.525898, 12.79079 , 16.295562, 13.512996, 14.407979,...
 y: array([[18.649103, 13.157682, 11.264763, 16.099163, 15.2293  , 17.854499,
        11.691586, 13.412066, 15.023189, 15.598455],
       [13.157682, 13.612502,  9.628261, 12.659313, 13.559437, 13.382417,..
```

Obviously, both the implementations differ. 
The questions are as follows:

- Is it acceptable for them to differ?
- Is my implementation wrong?
- If my implementation is wrong, how do I fix it?
- If my implementation  is correct, when is it safe to use `scipy.linalg.expm`?

I have seen the following questions:

- [Matrix exponentiation with scipy: expm, expm2 and expm3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167237/matrix-exponentiation-with-scipy-expm-expm2-and-expm3)

Comment: If anyone short on time here is the Jupyter notebook version . https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5pia3doed369g3/expm_compare.ipynb?dl=0

Comment: Two things: 1) `eigh` is only to be used on Hermitian or real symmetric matrices, which your example is not. 2) The inverse of a unitary is it's conjugate transpose, going through `inv` instead is wasteful and introduces unnecessary numerical error. --- I'd assume it's 1) that causes the difference you are observing.

Comment: I tried to fix 1) in https://www.dropbox.com/s/9o9j40hf82toykg/expm_compare-eig-real.ipynb?dl=0   and  https://www.dropbox.com/s/g046aem8lrrq2jy/expm_compare-eig-complex.ipynb?dl=0 . But still something seems wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from a mathematical approach the definition of exponential of a matrix is made using the Taylor series of the exponential, so:

let A be a diagonal square matrix:
[image]

the problem arise when A is a generic square matrix, so before doing the exponential you will need do diagonalize it using eigenvalue and eigenvectors:
[image]

with U the matrix of eigenvectors and Lambda the matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

at this point we are close to finding what is an exponential of a matrix:
[image]

now lets implement this result in a simple script:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.linalg as ln

>>> A = [[2/3, -4/3, 2],
         [5/6, 4/3, -2],
         [5/6, -2/3, 0]]
>>> A = np.matrix(A)
>>> print(A)
[[ 0.66666667 -1.33333333  2.        ]
 [ 0.83333333  1.33333333 -2.        ]
 [ 0.83333333 -0.66666667  0.        ]]

>>> eigvalue, eigvectors = np.linalg.eig(A)
>>> print("eigvalue: ", eigvalue)
>>> print("eigvectors:")
>>> print(eigvectors)
eigvalue:  [ 1. -1.  2.]
eigvectors:
[[ 0.81649658  0.27216553  0.87287156]
 [ 0.40824829 -0.68041382 -0.21821789]
 [ 0.40824829 -0.68041382  0.43643578]]

>>> e_Lambda = np.eye(np.size(A, 0))*(np.exp(eigvalue))
>>> print(e_Lambda)
[[2.71828183 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.36787944 0.        ]
 [0.         0.         7.3890561 ]]

>>> e_A = eigvectors*e_Lambda*eigvectors.I
>>> print(e_A)
[[ 2.3265481  -6.22769903  7.01116649]
 [ 0.97933433  4.27520659 -3.51559341]
 [ 0.97933433 -3.11384951  3.87346269]]

>>> e_A2 = ln.expm(A)
>>> print(e_A2)
[[ 2.3265481  -6.22769903  7.01116649]
 [ 0.97933433  4.27520659 -3.51559341]
 [ 0.97933433 -3.11384951  3.87346269]]

>>> np.testing.assert_allclose(e_A, e_A2)
>>> print(e_A - e_A2)
[[-1.77635684e-15  1.77635684e-15 -8.88178420e-16]
 [ 4.44089210e-16 -1.77635684e-15  8.88178420e-16]
 [-2.22044605e-16  0.00000000e+00  4.44089210e-16]]
```

we see that the result is basically the same, so i think it's safe to use `scipy.linalg.expm` for matrix exponentiation.

i created a [repo](https://github.com/simone-viozzi/matrix_exponentiation) with the notebook for further testing.

Comment: yes, check the latest commit on the repo, it show a test with a complex matrix