# Numpy apply function on each sub matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose there is a numpy matrix of shape (3, 3, 3), so there will be three 3*3 matrices, and I want to apply a function (matrix exponential) to each of the matrices, what would be a better way to do this rather than using a for loop? Below is my way of implementing it using a for loop. Thank you

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm

X = np.random.rand(3, 3, 3)
y = np.zeros((3, 3, 3))
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    y[i] = expm(X[i])
```

Comment: I think that is as good as it gets in NumPy. This isn't the first time someone asked about applying `expm` along an axis (some mistakenly called it "vectorizing" but vectorized ufuncs operate on elements, not subarrays), and there wasn't any solution not using a for-loop or list comprehension . `expm` just wasn't designed to iterate an axis like many functions were, e.g. `sum`.

Comment: Since the exponentiation will be done per square matrix, I don't think there is any particular advantage in "vectorization" (if possible). Please feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @amzon-ex. It's always better to bury the loop in C if you want to go fast

Comment: Try wrapping something in numba.njit

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45167237/2988730. Might be worth doing a simple Taylor expansion or so manually. That should be trivially vectorizable